# How do I get multiple metrics from ElasticSearch logs

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a service, and I log all HTTP requests made against this service into ElasticSearch. Each log holds `method` and `path` attributes like so:

```json
{
    "_source": {
        "data": {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "https://example.com/myResource/12345"
        }
    }
}
```

Given that the service is quite large, there are a number of different routes defined within it, and one route may have multiple HTTP methods associated with it:

```
    POST https://example.com/myResource
    # The following contain example IDs for myResource
    GET  https://example.com/myResource/12345 
    PUT  https://example.com/myResource/23456
    GET  https://example.com/myResource/34567/findRelatedResources
    POST https://example.com/altResource
    # The following contain example IDs for altResource
    GET  https://example.com/altResource/45678
    PUT  https://example.com/altResource/56789
    GET  https://example.com/altResource/67890/findRelatedResources
    ...
```

I'm trying to get the request metrics for each **valid** permutation of `path` and `method`, but given the number of permutations I'm not sure how to efficiently write such an aggregation.